# Android: how to repeat Android Notifications based on time

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to implement notifications repeatedly based on android. for eg. daily at 8AM, 8PM. I have gone through the `AlarmManager` and `Notification` classes but i'm not sure about how to use/configure `setRepeating()`/`setInexactRepeating()` methods for my requirement. Can anybody suggest which is the best method to use and what are the parameter need to send for `setXXXRepeating()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setRepeating` with 12 hours interval and first trigger time at 8PM/AM.

```
long interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12; //12 hours interval
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, absoluteTime, interval, intent);
```

Where `absoluteTime` points eaither to 8am or to 8pm (whichever comes next).